# Facebook C# SDK: what is account_id and how do I obtain it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-rest-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to implement the ads.createAdreportSchedules example found here:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

The account_id is set in the example.  However, I'm not sure what this is.  I know what my Application ID is but not my Account ID (I only have username/password).  What is "account_id" and how can I obtain it from my account?

Also, the example always throws an exception ("Param schedule_specs-time_next_ref must be a timestamp in the future") even though the code clearly sets one with a future date. Any idea of how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you're trying to implement method of Facebook Ads API. You can use the Ads API as an alternative to the Facebook Advertising Manager tool.
You can find more information about Ads APi here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/adsapi

AccountID is an ID of ads account. User of your application can have multiple ads accounts. You can get account ids that the current session user owns by [ads.getAccounts](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ads.getAccounts) API call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find your own ads account id, go to

http://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/accounts.php

This will show you a list of ad accounts you have access to.  One of the columns in the list is the account id of each account.  Hope this helps.  This is the id that the Facebook Ads API is referring to.